# reverse() not working on map() Component state ( Firebase )

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase, react-router

**1. reverse() not working properly on Child Component**

I have this state on a Component

```
this.state = {
    score_board_data:[]
}
```

and the following `componentDidMount` lifecycle

```
componentDidMount(){

    const tempArray = this.state.score_board_data

    this.dataBase.orderByChild("player_score").on('child_added', snap =>{
        tempArray.push({
            player_score: snap.val().player_score,
            player_name: snap.val().player_name
        });
        this.setState({score_board_data:tempArray});
     });
}
```

When I use the map() function on the state

```
this.state.score_board_data.map((player,i)=>{
    return(
        <tr key={i}>
              <td>{player.player_name}</td>
              <td>{player.player_score}</td>
        </tr>
    )
});
```

I get sorting based on this:

```
.orderByChild("player_score")
```

which for looks like this ( 
125,
150,
150,
150,
150,
150,
175,
225,
300,
325
)

Now I want to reverse it, so I use the `reverse()` method on the map() function like this

```
this.state.score_board_data.reverse().map( ....
```

i get this 
   ( 325,
225,
150,
150,
150,
125,
150,
150,
175,
300 ) 
..... which is not reversed at all :D

Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

**2. componentWillUnmount dilemma.**

I have a parent Component, which uses Google Firebase

```
//child
this.app = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);
this.database = this.app.database().ref().child("numbers");
```

I pass the database ref to the child component as a prop

```
//child props from parent 
dataBase={this.database}
```

I use react router to navigate from parent to child and back ...

but when I add an element to the database in the parent component and use the router to get to the child component which uses the same database reference as the parent I  get this error ...

**Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.**

I think I need to add some code in the child `componentWillUnmount()` to  remove the database from it .... sadly I  don't know how

```
//child
componentWillUnmount(){
}
```

I looked up on Google and here but couldn't figure it out

Comment: Why not order the data in descending order in the Firebase query?

Answer (score 0):

[Array#reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) does reverse the Array in place, like [Array#sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

So you don't just reverse the output you've created by `map()`, but instead you reverse the input `this.state.score_board_data`. Then you `push()` the 300 to the *(reversed)* Array.

Solution: change the order in wich you call the functions

```
this.state.score_board_data.map(...).reverse()
```